# WooCommerce associate 'alternate widget' products to membership plan(s)

Tags: woocommerce

I have an installation of WooCommerce but the out-of-box product types dont suit our needs. Essentially we are trying to 'loosely' build a subscription site but in reviewing others plugins etc..none seemed to fit our requirements and/or didnt feel 'solid'.

FLOW:
User will purchase a membership plan (woo membership plan product) and gain access to a page which will list out all the available 'widgets products' based on the purchased plan. On that page we test for active memberships etc...and then show the appropriate widget products.

***'widget products' = non-woo commerce product type (ie. PPT, Vimeo, YT, any other asset than can be put on a web page. etc..)***

Currently this relationship between purchased membership plan and widget products is based on string categories associated to the widget products via ACF PRO form fields and then string tested for each membership plan on the newly accessed page.

ISSUE: the cateogry and membership plan string tests work... but is not maintainable from an admin POV, thus this question.

IDEAL: Find all memberships the user is active in and simply return all widget products related to the membership, i.e. no string tests

QUESTION: Has anyone related products to woocommerce membership plan(s) that were NOT woo commerce product types. Could we create a unique product type for woo commerce? or are there alternate methods for creating this relationship outside of string tests?

I know this is more a discussion thread but I'm hopeful this may help others that dont want to follow the WooCommerce Flow in its entirety.

Thanks in advance for any comments.